# How many possible different telephone numbers consisting of two zeros, three fours, one five and one seven are there?

Tags: probability

In a city every telephone number has 7 digits where the first digit is never a 0.

How many possible different telephone numbers consisting of two zeros, three fours, one five and one seven are there?

I would have started with calculating how many different numbers are there consisting of two zeros, three fours, one five and one seven including the numbers with 0 at the beginning. I used $\frac{7!}{1! 1! 2! 3!}= 420$.

Then i would have calculated the number of numbers with 0 in the prefix and substracted it but I do not know how to calculate it.

Thank you for any help or hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first digit is zero, then the remaining six digits are an arbitrary permutation of one zero, three fours, one five, and one seven.  Hence, using your multiset formula again, $${6\choose 1,1,1,3}=\frac{6!}{1!1!1!3!}$$

Comment: ha now i see it. thank you so much man!

Comment: my pleasure, glad to help.